# Populating dropdown from selectlist query returns System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem in dropdownlist

Tags: c#, linq

I had a dropdown which was working perfectly fine but had to be edited because I needed to perform a join on a second table and I came up with the following.

```
ViewBag.Type = new SelectList(from r in db.Departments
                              join s in db.Payment on r.departmentId equals s.deparmentId_FK
                              where r.myID == myID
                              select new SelectListItem
                                         {
                                              Value = s.paymentTypeId.ToString(),
                                              Text = s.name
                                         }).ToList();
```

And in my view

```
@Html.DropDownList("Type", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Type, "--- Tous ---")
@Html.DropDownList("Type", ViewBag.Type as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, "Choose Type", new { @class = "form-control listbox" })
@Html.DropDownList("Type", new SelectList(ViewBag.Type, "Value", "Text"), "Choose Type", new { @class = "form-control listbox" })`
```

The problem being experienced is that despite the items being filtered correctly I can't get the data to show anything apart from `System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem`. I have taken steps from other questions but I can't shake this issue.

Appreciate it if I could know what was missing.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Try just selecting a new anonymous object. Depending on what version of `Entity Framework` you are using, the problem may be that it is trying to evaluate the `Select` statement on the server or the client. Which ever one it is doing apparently does not like trying to select a new `SelectListItem`. Example below.

```
ViewBag.Type = new SelectList((from r in db.Departments
                              join s in db.Payment on r.departmentId equals s.deparmentId_FK
                              where r.myID == myID
                              select new
                                         {
                                              Value = s.paymentTypeId.ToString(),
                                              Text = s.name
                                         }).ToList());
```

Comment: Sadly, this wasnt the issue, I added your suggestion and nothing has changed.

Comment: Also your view bag is already a selectlist so take out the cast

Comment: I changed `select new selectListItem` to `select new ` and now i get `{value = 1 , text= apples}`

Comment: I updated my answer to reflect your findings @Niana.

Comment: Unfortunately it made no difference, the results are the same